# TYPO3: Uploads in backend module

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have to implement a "Book" management in the Backend. Each book has a PDF preview, a title, description and so on... 
The BE user should be able to upload a PDF and set a title, description etc. through a Backend module.

The created Book should be selectable in a plugin (or content element ?) so it can be display in the frontend. 
Also, the uploaded PDF should only be downloadable by a certain group of FE users.

I don't know how to handle the upload part in the backend. I didn't find much info online beside this upload example: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example it seems quite complex and I'm not sure if it's the best solution for me.

What would be the best way to proceed for my task ?

Comment: Is having a custom and dedicated backend module for managing these books a requirement? Otherwise there would be the possibility to use the regular form processing of the backend using the Web>List module...

Comment: You are right but I have to implement statistics as well .. such as download count etc. So I think the module is a must

Answer (score 2):

Use File Abstraction Layer (FAL). You don't need the example in backend, but it's great for frontend upload.

**Domain/Model/Book.php**

```
...

/**
 * File (file references)
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
 * @lazy
 */
protected $files = NULL;


/**
 * Construct
 *
 *
 */
public function __construct() {
    //Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
    $this->initStorageObjects();
}

/**
 * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
 * Do not modify this method!
 * It will be rewritten on each save in the extension builder
 * You may modify the constructor of this class instead
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function initStorageObjects() {
    $this->files = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}

/**
 * Set files (file references)
 *
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference> $files
 * @return void
 */
public function setFiles(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $files) {
    $this->files = $files;
}

/**
 * Get files (file references)
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference> $files
 */
public function getFiles() {
    return $this->files;
}

...
```

**TCA/tx_yourextension_domain_model_book.php**

```
    ...

    'files' => [
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:werkhandkunst/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:file',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'files', ['
                maxitems' => 25,
            ],
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
        ),
    ],

    ...
```

**ext_tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE tx_yourextension_domain_model_book (
        ...

        files int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

        ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks Heinz, I did what you suggested and added <f:form.upload property="pdf" ></f:form.upload> I my view but I get this error when I submit the form: Exception while property mapping at property path "pdf.error": No file reference (sys_file_reference) was found for given UID: "4"

Comment: File upload in backend will be done by TCA. Why and where did you use <f:form.upload property="pdf" ></f:form.upload>?

Comment: I did add the form in the backend module of my extension. I have a "BackendBookController" with a "newAction", so I added the form inside the "New.html" file. I am new to typo3, I guess this wasn't the right way?